# Set up dual boot Debian (Mint LMDE) Linux + Windows 8.1 **without** efi

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, multi-boot, mbr, grub2

The specifics is that in my case **Windows 8.1** is installed **not in EFI mode**: so the partition table is in msdos/fat format and there is no efi partition.

Unfortunately:

1. All how-tos and manuals I've found about dual-booting Linux with Windows 8.1 are about EFI.
2. All how-tos and manuals I've found about setting dual-boot with GRUB without EFI are about Windows ≤7 . And these instructions didn't work for me.

**How can I setup correctly working dual-boot?**

**Linux + Windows 8.1 without EFI.**

I would be grateful for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this.

The solution is to

1. Edit file **/etc/grub.d/40_custom**:

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> exec tail -n +3 $0
>
> # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
>
> # menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
>
> # the 'exec tail' line above.
>
> menuentry "Windows 8" {  
>      insmod ntfs  
>      set root='(hd0,1)'  
>      ntldr /bootmgr
> }
> ```

2. Backup mbr `dd if=/dev/sda of=/home/ivan/Dropbox/config/portatil/sda.mbr-2016-05-27 count=512` and run `grub-install --recheck /dev/sda`